# Traversal of sklearn decision tree

Tags: python, scikit-learn, decision-tree

How do I do the breadth first search traversal of  the sklearn decision tree?

In my code i have tried sklearn.tree_ library and used various function such as tree_.feature and tree_.threshold to understand the structure of the tree. But these functions do the dfs traversal of the tree if I want to do bfs how should i do it?

Suppose

```
clf1 = DecisionTreeClassifier( max_depth = 2 )
clf1 = clf1.fit(x_train, y_train)
```

this is my classifier and the decision tree produced is

[image]

Then I have traversed the tree using following function

```
def encoding(clf, features):
l1 = list()
l2 = list()

for i in range(len(clf.tree_.feature)):
    if(clf.tree_.feature[i]>=0):
        l1.append( features[clf.tree_.feature[i]])
        l2.append(clf.tree_.threshold[i])
    else:
        l1.append(None)
        print(np.max(clf.tree_.value))
        l2.append(np.argmax(clf.tree_.value[i]))

l = [l1 , l2]

return np.array(l)
```

and the output produced is

```
array([['address', 'age', None, None, 'age', None, None],
       [0.5, 17.5, 2, 1, 15.5, 1, 1]], dtype=object)
```

where 1st array is feature of node or if it leaf noed then it is labelled as none and 2nd array is threshold for feature node and for class node it is class but this is dfs traversal of tree i want to do bfs traversal what should i do ?

As I am new to stack overflow kindly suggest how to improve the question description and what other information should i add if any to explain my problem further.

X_train (sample)
[image: X_train]

y_train (sample)
[image: y_train]

Comment: Please provide a [MCVE] (which you can do it easily for this question by adapting some example from the documentation with dummy data).

Comment: Could you give some context *why* you would like to do that? I sense this might be a case of the dreaded [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: @desertnaut I have elaborated it further  if want any more information kindly tell

Comment: @Dion i am using this trees for initial population of genetic algorithm so i want to encode them into a chromosome that's why

Comment: Please, take the last extra step to make your example completely reproducible by providing `x_train` and `y_train` in the question - as said, can be dummy data, and there are lots of examples in the scikit-learn documentation which you can adapt (or use [`make_classification`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.datasets.make_classification.html)).

Comment: @desertnaut i have added sample X_train and y_train data

Comment: OK, your question has been answered. For the *next* time, keep in mind that, in order to make your issue fully reproducible (thus greatly increasing the chances to get a helpful answer), you need to provide the data in a form usable for potential respondents (not the case now); that's why I insisted pointing you in the documentation examples - it's not necessary to provide the exact data you are using, just a means for others to reproduce the issue and verify their suggested answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it:

```py
from collections import deque

tree = clf.tree_

stack = deque()
stack.append(0)  # push tree root to stack

while stack:
    current_node = stack.popleft()

    # do whatever you want with current node
    # ...

    left_child = tree.children_left[current_node]
    if left_child >= 0:
        stack.append(left_child)

    right_child = tree.children_right[current_node]
    if right_child >= 0:
        stack.append(right_child)
```

This uses a `deque` to keep a stack of the nodes to process next. Since we remove elements from the left and add them to the right, this should represent a breadth-first traversal.

---

For actual use, I suggest you turn this into a generator:

```py
from collections import deque

def breadth_first_traversal(tree):
    stack = deque()
    stack.append(0)

    while stack:
        current_node = stack.popleft()

        yield current_node

        left_child = tree.children_left[current_node]
        if left_child >= 0:
            stack.append(left_child)

        right_child = tree.children_right[current_node]
        if right_child >= 0:
            stack.append(right_child)
```

Then, you only need minimal changes to your original function:

```py
def encoding(clf, features):
    l1 = list()
    l2 = list()

    for i in breadth_first_traversal(clf.tree_):
        if(clf.tree_.feature[i]>=0):
            l1.append( features[clf.tree_.feature[i]])
            l2.append(clf.tree_.threshold[i])
        else:
            l1.append(None)
            print(np.max(clf.tree_.value))
            l2.append(np.argmax(clf.tree_.value[i]))

    l = [l1 , l2]

    return np.array(l)
```

Comment: It worked. I didn't know about retrieval of child node using  tree.children_left[current_node] and tree.children_right[current_node]. Thanks for answering.

Comment: I also wanted to know can we store the tree into array in way that it appears to be a complete binary tree so that children of ith node is stored at 2i th and 2i +1 th position

Comment: This should be a new question.

Comment: ok so how should i do it should i include all these details and then add this. Also I thought of a method  but I think it's highly inefficient.