# BFS traversal of sklearn decision tree

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, decision-tree

How do I do the breadth first search traversal of the sklearn decision tree?

In my code i have tried sklearn.tree_ library and used various function such as tree_.feature and tree_.threshold to understand the structure of the tree. But these functions do the dfs traversal of the tree if I want to do bfs how should i do it?

Suppose

```
clf1 = DecisionTreeClassifier( max_depth = 2 )
clf1 = clf1.fit(x_train, y_train)
```

this is my classifier and the decision tree produced is

[image: Decision tree]

Then I have traversed the tree using following function

```
def encoding(clf, features):
l1 = list()
l2 = list()

for i in range(len(clf.tree_.feature)):
    if(clf.tree_.feature[i]>=0):
        l1.append( features[clf.tree_.feature[i]])
        l2.append(clf.tree_.threshold[i])
    else:
        l1.append(None)
        print(np.max(clf.tree_.value))
        l2.append(np.argmax(clf.tree_.value[i]))

l = [l1 , l2]

return np.array(l)
```

and the output produced is

array([['address', 'age', None, None, 'age', None, None],
       [0.5, 17.5, 2, 1, 15.5, 1, 1]], dtype=object)
where 1st array is feature of node or if it leaf node then it is labelled as none and 2nd array is threshold for feature node and for class node it is class but this is dfs traversal of tree i want to do bfs traversal what should i do ?
The above part has been answered.

I wanted to know can we store the tree into array in way that it appears to be a complete binary tree so that children of ith node is stored at 2i + 1  th and 2i +2 th index?

[image]

For above tree output produced is 
array([['address', 'age', None, None], [0.5, 15.5, 1, 1]], dtype=object)

but the desired output is

array([['address',  None, 'age', None, None, None, None], [0.5, -1,  15.5, -1, -1, 1 , 1]], dtype=object)

If values is none in 1st array and -1 in 2nd array that would mean that node does not exist. So here age which is right child of address is found at 2 * 0 + 2 = 2
index in array and similarly left and right child of age are found at 2 * 2 + 1 = 5th index and 2 * 2 + 2 = 6th index of the array respectively.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Traversal of sklearn decision tree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61203080/traversal-of-sklearn-decision-tree)

Comment: Yes you have solved the traversal part of the question now I  want to store the tree in such a way that the children of ith node is stored at 2i th and 2i +1 th position of array.

Comment: @Dion can you help me with this?

Comment: Please update the questions with expected (example) inputs and outputs.

Comment: @Dion I have added an example please let me know if you need any further clarification

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```py
def reformat_tree(clf):
    tree = clf.tree_

    feature_out = np.full((2 ** tree.max_depth), -1, dtype=tree.feature.dtype)
    threshold_out = np.zeros((2 ** tree.max_depth), dtype=tree.threshold.dtype)

    stack = []
    stack.append((0, 0))

    while stack:
        current_node, new_node = stack.pop()

        feature_out[new_node] = tree.feature[current_node]
        threshold_out[new_node] = tree.threshold[current_node]

        left_child = tree.children_left[current_node]
        if left_child >= 0:
            stack.append((left_child, 2 * current_node + 1))

        right_child = tree.children_right[current_node]
        if right_child >= 0:
            stack.append((right_child, 2 * current_node + 2))

    return feature_out, threshold_out
```

I can't test it on your tree since you still haven't given a way to reproduce it, but it should work.

The function returns features and thresholds in the desired format. Feature value is `-1` is the node doesn't exist, and `-2` if the node is a leaf.

This works by traversing the tree and keeping track of the current position.